# Is this a good approach for ip address to location?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, geolocation

I'm on Ruby on Rails 3.1.x trying to find out ip address <-> location.

I'm following the approach described here http://def-end.com/post/3582366278/how-to-determine-country-by-ip-address which parses through a .dat file to determine the country of origin from an IP address.

Is this efficient? Or, would a query run on a database be more efficient (i.e. through a ip_to_location table)?

Comment: Is it too slow right now? What do you mean by "efficient"? Is it a bottleneck right now? The code looks like it loads the entire geoip database from a file whenever an ip lookup is performed, which is probably slower than doing a table lookup. However, it may be good enough for your use case. You need to define what "efficient" means to you, and what "too slow" would be.

Comment: We are expecting ip lookups to work in production, on every user page view. i.e. user loads a page, we fire-up some kind of ip to location look-up. As to how many page views a minute/hour/day. Lets just say we want to prepare for this long term

Comment: How long does it take now for a single request? Is that time acceptable? That seems like the first question to answer when you are trying to decide if something is too slow or not. Like I said above, it *seems* like it would be kindof inefficient to load the database on every IP lookup, which it looks like the example code does. However, unless you know how long it takes and you know how long a faster implementation takes you don't really know if you have a problem or not.

Comment: Jergason, at the moment, testing it on our local server. So far, loads fine, since we are only a few developers accessing it on a given time. Don't want to push anything onto our production server until we are sure